# Jquery isn't registering change in checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have JQuery code that looks like this:

```
 <script>
        $('.tr_clone input.part-class').change(function () {
            let Id = $(this).attr('id');
            let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');
            var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
            var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
            $clone.find('td');
            $tr.after($clone);
        });
 </script>
```

And here is my rendered view:

```
 <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                       //headers (removed for conciseness)
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        //td's (removed for conciseness)
                    </tr>
                </table>
                    <h4><b>Parts in Item</b></h4>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            //headers (removed for conciseness)                    
                        </tr>
                        <tbody>
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Parts_0__ID" name="Parts[0].ID" type="hidden" value="346" /><input id="Parts_0__PartID" name="Parts[0].PartID" type="hidden" value="600601" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ItemID must be a number." data-val-required="The ItemID field is required." id="Parts_0__ItemID" name="Parts[0].ItemID" type="hidden" value="117" />                                                    
      <tr class="tr_clone">

           
               <td>
                     <a p-id=346 style='color:#FF00FF;' href='#'>600601</a>
               </td>
               <td>
                     Supply - Packing Carton, 9&quot; x 8&quot; x 8&quot;, MU/AX
                     <input id="Parts_0__PartName" name="Parts[0].PartName" type="hidden" value="Supply - Packing Carton, 9&quot; x 8&quot; x 8&quot;, MU/AX" />
               </td>
               <td style="font-weight:bold">
                     1
                     <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field QtyInItem must be a number." data-val-required="The QtyInItem field is required." id="Parts_0__QtyInItem" name="Parts[0].QtyInItem" type="hidden" value="1" />

                </td>
                <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="all346" class="part-class" data-partId="346" checked>
                </td>
                <td>
                      <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedActionType field is required." id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Transfer" />
                </td>
                <td>
                      <input id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Harvest" />
                </td>
                <td>
                      <input id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Dispose" />
                </td>
       </tr>
                   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I run this code using JFiddle, I am able to get the expected result I want (a duplicated row).

But when I run it through visual studio, the checkbox never hits my JQuery code.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in your browser console? Also after $('.tr_clone input.part-class').change(function () { add console.log('change event') - and see if event is rasied

Answer (score 0):

You must consider the **td** tag in your hierarchy selector:

```
$('.tr_clone td input.part-class')
```

Also the rigth method to invoke is **click(function(e))** instead of **change(function())**

Other tip that if you're loading dinamically that content, you should load using the **on** function.

Complete function invoke:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tr_clone td input.part-class', function() {
    //some code
});
```

Comment: "You must consider the td tag in your hierarchy selector" this is not correct. The OP would only need the td tag if they were using `>` in their selector.